# JHipster - Angular 6 : How to include the css files from 3rd party modules in index.html?

Tags: angular, jhipster

JHipster - Angular 6 
How to include the css/scss files from 3rd party libraries (example FontAwesome) in index.html ?
Relative path issue.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question to include more details, the exact error you're facing and what you've tried already to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from index.html, the best practise is import in vendor.scss file.

Please follow this steps:

1. you have to install or import that library in your JHipster project.
2. then you have to import that library in main css or scss module. in JHipster content/scss/vendor.scss is responsible for provide style sheet.

example:

> npm i font-awesome --save

now you have a font-awesome library in your project.
now import that in vendor.scss like this:

> @import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

now you can use font-awesome css in your project.

Comment: Thank you, It was really useful.

Comment: @Sudheendra can you please accepting an answer(check it) if it useful, so other people can reach directly to the solution.